# Is it possible spin-up an Ubuntu VM using Virtual Box with the new ARM-based CPU?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, virtualization, virtualbox

Is it possible to spin-up an Ubuntu-based VM on an Apple Silicon MacBook Pro?

I found a `jammy-desktop-arm64.iso` file on this [link](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/) and tried it but I was unable to make it work (as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405124/install-ubuntu-desktop-22-04-arm64-on-macos-apple-silicon-m1-pro-max-in-parall) post).

I've tried but without any success. The message shown is :

> ```
> No bootable medium found!  
> Please insert a bootable medium and reboot.
> ```

Am I doing something wrong ? Is it possible to run any version of Ubuntu on an Apple Silicon MacBook Pro using VirtualBox? (I am using the latest version, which is Version 7.0.6_BETA4 r155176 (Qt6.3.0).)

Also, the amd64 version of the ISO doesn't work either.

Comment: The error message you got was not about Ubuntu running in a VM, it is the VirtualBox telling you it can’t find bootable media.  How are you installing Ubuntu?

Comment: Also, you’re using a BETA of VBox and an obscure source for Ubuntu.  This should raise red flags.

Comment: @AndyB Why would an AMD64 version of Ubuntu work in a virtualization on an ARM CPU?  The instructions you link specify using Parallels, why don't you use Parallels?

Comment: Well, the bootable media is there, I don't know why I keep getting this error. I don't know where to find the official ARM ubuntu ISO. The ISO is linked correctly as per the screenshot here https://imgur.com/a/cMncMGA. I am super familiar with VirtualBox, that's why, I like it especially the Clone State option. I can try Parallel (hope it includes a similar Clone option because multipass doesn't ).

Comment: The [current documentation of VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#hostossupport) states the following. *"An installer package is available for macOS/Arm64, for systems using an Apple silicon CPU. With this package, you can run some guest operating systems for Intel x86/x64 CPUs in an emulation."* There does not appear to be support for ARM Ubuntu.

Comment: You want to run an [ARM64 version of Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Desktop](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/). VMware has a free [Person Use License](https://customerconnect.vmware.com/en/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal-13) for Fusion Player, which runs on Apple Silicon. According to VMware you should be able to install an [ARM64 version of Ubuntu 22.10 Server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm) as a [guest](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/pdf/VMware_GOS_Compatibility_Guide.pdf), when using Fusion Player 13.